# FB App closes as soon as it is displayed with presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction on ios 6

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When i start Facebook from my App, the dialog can't be posted, because the FB App closes as soon as the share dialog is displayed.

completion handler is not called. No Error. No Success.

```
   id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];

   action[@"mystory"] = @{
                            @"fbsdk:create_object": @YES,
                            @"type": @"appname:mystory",
                            @"title":@"title",
                            @"url": @"http://www.foo.bar",
                            @"description":@"text"
                            };


    FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                          actionType:@"appname:myaction"
                                 previewPropertyName:@"mystory"
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                 if(error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                 } else {
                                                     NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                 }
                                             }];
```

Does any body see what i'm doing wrong?

If I use simply presentShareDialogWithLink it works correctely.

**Edit:
If i pass the appcall without any url it works! Why?**

```
   action[@"mystory"] = @{
                            @"fbsdk:create_object": @YES,
                            @"type": @"appname:mystory",
                            @"title":@"title",
                            @"description":@"text"
                            };
```

Comment: The documentation Facebook provides about this is quite poor... but I believe that if you pass a URL, Facebook tries to scrap it looking for Open Graph metatags, and if one of them is wrong, the whole thing goes wrong. Try putting your URL in the Facebook debugger to see if it finds any errors: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I am under the impression that you can create user-owned objects that bypass the need for a backend server. Is this accurate? Furthermore, I think that @"fbsdk:create_object": @YES, actually does that. IS shareDialog supposed to bring the user to the native iOS facebook app?

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue using the sample code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/ (it was definitely going into the Share Dialog section of the code rather than the Feed Dialog): my app was going into the background and the facebook app was appearing, only to be immediately dismissed again, returning to my app.

After a little searching, I came across a couple of references to the URL-handling setup and decided to double-check the app integration. I discovered there were a few things I'd missed in moving from 3.2 to 3.5, specifically the FacebookDisplayName entry in the plist, the changes to the openURL function & enabling the share dialog beta feature, as described here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/

After all that, the problem has gone away: the dialog appears correctly and I can share things happily. Unfortunately I can't tell you which one of the above changes actually fixed the issue, but it's probably worth double-checking them all.

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

- "appname" is your actual app's namespace
- "mystory" is the actual object type
- "myaction" is the name of your action

And you need a working URL that you host. The one you provided "http://www.foo.bar" cannot be scrapped by Facebook and will not work.

Comment: This is an example code, my actual code is different. Other Property Names and other Urls... www.foo.bar is a standard for examples, myapp,mystory and myaction are examples. The code i provide should be suitable for every body who has the same problem.

Comment: I understand, I was just urging you to double check all the information entered. I had the same problem as you and it was fixed when I used a working URL hosted by myself

Answer (score -1):

When you have the URL in the appcall does it match the one you have entered in the App Domains box within your app configuration on Facebook? If the url in your appcall and the one you have entered in your app configuration on Facebook are different, then the call will fail as yours does and could be the reason.